# Cocoon gem - Nested form saves elements, asks for a new template file and shows empty fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, cocoon-gem

I know this question have asked countless times, but I didn't find anyone with the issue I have.

It may be important to note that this is a single resource.

**models/basic.rb**

```
class Basic < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :social_networks
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :social_networks, reject_if: :all_blank, allow_destroy: true
  mount_uploader :logo, LogoUploader
end
```

**models/social_network.rb**

```
class SocialNetwork < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :basic
end
```

**controllers/basic_controller.rb**

```
def show
end

def new
  @basic = Basic.new
  @basic.social_networks.build
end

def edit
end

private

# Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
def set_basic
  @basic = Basic.first
end

# Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white 
list through.
def basic_params
  params.require(:basic).permit(:base_title, :resume, :logo, social_networks_attributes: [:id, :name, :url])
  end
end
```

**views/basics/_form.html.erb**

```
<%= form_with(model: @basic, local: true, url: basics_path) do |f| %>
  <div id="social_networks">
    <%= f.fields_for :social_networks do |sn| %>
      <%= render 'social_networks', f: sn %>
    <% end %>

    <div class="links">
      <%= link_to_add_association 'Ajouter', f, :social_networks %>
    </div>
  </div>
<%= end %>
```

**_social_network_fields.html.erb**

```
<div class="nested-fields">
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %>
    <%= f.text_field :name, placeholder: 'Nom' %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :url %>
    <%= f.text_field :url, placeholder: 'Lien' %>
  </div>

  <div class="links">
    <%= link_to_remove_association 'Supprimer', f %>
  </div>
</div>
```

As said in the question title, my form works fine and saves up the elements I fill in correctly. However, when I want to edit, I get an error saying that it can't find a template for the resource (it waits for a file named `_social_networks.html.erb`). When I add it (and let it blank), I get the form as if I want to create some new resources.

What did I do wrong?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You wrote

```
<%= render 'social_networks', f: sn %>
```

But your view is _social_networks_fields.html.erb

Cant you just rename _social_networks_fields.html.erb to _social_networks.html.erb?

Also change your add association link:

```
<div class="links">
  <%= link_to_add_association 'Ajouter', f, :social_networks, :partial => 'social_networks' %>
</div>
```

Or just use

```
<%= render 'social_networks_fields', f: sn %>
```

And you don't need the social_networks.html.erb

Comment: I tried, what happens is that nothing gets displayed when I click on "add". It's really weird, because I tried to have **both** the files, `_social_networks.html.erb` and `social_networks_field.html.erb`. If I copy/paste the content from the file to other, it works, so it means it needs one file to save the elements, and another to let the user edit it.

Comment: Thank you, it worked! Very clever to tell Rails which template to use, I'd do it if I knew it was possible